# Eloquent way to determine if any variables are equal

Tags: typescript

I have a class and some optional configuration options on the constructor. The rule is that **none** of the values are allowed to be `===` to each other. What is an eloquent way to determine if any are equal to each other. All characters are strings, and will also have a validation to ensure that none are longer than 1 char.

```
constructor(options?: ClassOptions){
    this.leftWrapperChar = options.leftWrapperChar || '{';
    this.rightWrapperChar = options.rightWrapperChar || '}';
    this.commandChar = options.commandChar || '%';
    this.variableChar = options.variableChar || '+';
    this.commentChar = options.commentChar || '#';
    this.variableAssignmentChar = options.variableAssignmentChar || ':';
    this.stringEscapeChar = options.stringEscapeChar || '\\';
    // Determine if any are equal to each other
}
```

Obviously this could be accomplished with `a !== b && b !== c && c !== d && ...` but this list will likely grow and the permutations would be exponential.

My current solution is putting all options into an array and sorting them, then comparing them with the next index

```
const array = [
    this.leftWrapperChar, 
    this.rightWrapperChar, 
    this.commandChar, 
    this.variableChar, 
    this.commentChar, 
    this.variableAssignmentChar, 
    this.stringEscapeChar].sort();
for(let i=0; i< array.length - 1; i++){
    if(array[i] === array[i + 1]) 
        throw new Error('Options Error: All Options chars must be unique');
}
```

But I feel that there might be a more elegant way of handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant way? I believe not.
A better way? Don't use `Array#sort`. Use a simple loop instead. It will be cleaner and have a bit better performance.

```
function anyEqual(...args: any[]): boolean {
  const found = [];
  return Array.prototype.some.call(args, arg => {
    if (found.indexOf(arg) > -1) return true;
    found.push(arg);
  });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (anyEqual(...Object.keys(options).map(key => options[key]))) throw new Error;
```